# Sandboxing JavaScript output?

Tags: javascript, security, sandbox

Is it possible to sandbox JavaScript output? What I mean is that whenever a developer is doing document.write, X.appendChild(), x.replaceChild(), x.innerHTML, etc. he would not be able to directly affect the DOM -- and instead the update would have to go through my framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

- [Cross browser javascript sandbox](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2009/04/03/cross-browser-javascript-sandbox/)
- [JavaScript Sandbox](http://www.webatic.com/run/programming/js_sandbox.php)